# Number of Ways to Arrange Two Couples and A Single Person

Tags: combinatorics

> Two couples and a single person are seated at random in a row of five chairs. What is the probability at least one person is not beside his/her partner?

Let $P(A)$ denote the probability that both couples are seated together in the arrangement. 
Therefore, the probability that at least one person is not beside his/her partner should be
$$1-P(A)$$
The total number of arrangements is $5!$ and the number of arrangements for both couples sitting together is 
$$3!2!2!$$
So, the probability that at least one per
son is not beside his/her partner is $$ 1-\frac{3!2!2!}{5!}=\frac{4}{5}$$

Are there any errors in the solution and answer?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no errors, your solution is right